# Simulate an API Object and external Data returned, in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, oop

I am doing stuff inside the console to try and simulate some code that exists in production.
 It takes a callback from a call to an API and then does some stuff with the data returned.
Its quite standard stuff but I am trying to simulate the data object that the server returns from my code and I am getting nowhere.

I want to end up some a kind of object that I can assign custom param/value pairs to so that I can access it via dot syntax. E.g.

```
myObject.thing = value
```

This is the format that the data from the API returns in.
Is there a way in the console to create an anonymous object, then assign the values myself and use that to run through my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the console type the below:

```
>> class myObject 
?> attr :testparam 
?> end 
=> nil 
>> i = myObject.new 
=> #myObject...... 
>> i.testparam = "value" 
=> #myObject..... 
>> yourcode(i) 
=> results from yourcode...
```

Here we define a class with a param/property, then instantiate an object.
 
We assign a value to the param and pass this object (with `param/value`) into a function (`yourcode`) which processes the data from here.

hope that helps